# Trying to import a custom UITableViewCell keeps giving me a file not found lexical preprocessor error in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, import

Trying to import a custom UITableViewCell and it keeps giving me a file not found lexical preprocessor error. I can't figure it out.

ProductCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ProductCell : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet UILabel *descript;
    IBOutlet UILabel *productCode;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *prodImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *descript;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *productCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *prodImage;

@end
```

ProductCell.m

```
#import "ProductCell.h"


@implementation ProductCell

@synthesize descript;
@synthesize productCode;
@synthesize prodImage;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

In my UItableviewcontroller.h file I've tried to import as `@class` and not doesnt seem to make a difference. and in my implementation file i simply

```
#import "ProductCell.h"
```

why is this? what basic step am I missing. Importing it in implementation file should solve my issue. Tried cleaning project

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: exactly what error are you getting?

Comment: Also, if this is being seen in Xcode 4, does this error actually occur at build time, or just in the inline error display? If it's the latter, then it's a known issue and should be discussed on Apple's [Developer Forums](http://devforums.apple.com/).

Comment: Looks correct off hand, can you post the actual error?

Comment: clean and build should fix it

Comment: @Kevin Ballard it is xcode 4, but its at build time not in the inline. Ill post the actual error tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be an XCode4 bug. Despite the fact that the compiler shows an error, if you try running the project, it should work.

This is discussed in the Apple forums in the following places:

- https://devforums.apple.com/message/369278#369278
- https://devforums.apple.com/message/379512#379512
- https://devforums.apple.com/message/382662#382662

Answer (score 6):

Renaming the header file to something else and renaming it back to its original name did solve the problem for me.